# Java - Detecting changes to webpage ajax component loaded with htmlUnit

Tags: java, ajax, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit to load a webpage containing a dynamically updated ajax component using the following:-

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
URL url = new URL("https://live.xxx.com/en/ajax/getDetailedQuote/" + instrument);
WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.POST); 
HtmlPage redirectPage = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
```

This works and I get the contents of the page at the time of request.

I want however to be able to monitor and respond to changes on the page.

I tried the following:-

webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() {

```
        public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Content changed ");
        }
    });
```

But I only get "Content changed" when the page is first loaded, and not when it updates.

Answer (score 0):

I fear there is not really a solution with HtmlUnit (at least not out of the box). The webWindowContentChanged hook is only called if the (whole) page inside the window is replaced.

You can try to implement an DomChangeListener and attach that to the page (or maybe the body of the page).

If you like to track the ajax requests more on the http level you have the option to intercept the requests (see https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse for more details).

If you need more, please open an issue and we can discuss.